# Data Factory V2 copy Data Activities and Data flow ETL

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

My question about the Data Factory V2 copy-data activity i have 5 questions.

**Questions 1**

Should I use parquet file or **SQL server With 500 DTU** I want to transfer data fast to staging table or **staging**  parquet file

**Questions 2**

Copy data activity data integration Unit should i use **auto or 32 data integration Unit**

[image]

**Questions 3**

What benefit of using **degree of copy parallelism** should I use **Auto or use 32 again** I want to transfer everything quick as possible I have around 50 million rows every day.

**Questions 4**

**Data Flow Integration** run time so should I use General Purpose, Compute Optimized or Memory Optimized as I mention we have **50 million  rows** every day, so we want to process the data as quickly as possible and somehow cheap if we can in Data Flow

[image]

**Questions 5**

A bulk insert is better in Data Factory and Data flow Sink

Answer (score 1):

I think you have too many questions about too many topics, the answers to which will depend entirely on your desired end result. Even so, I will do my best to briefly address your situation.

If you are dealing with large volume and/or frequency, Data Flow (ADFDF) would probably be better than Copy activity. ADFDF runs on Spark via Data Bricks and is built from the ground up to run parallel workloads. Parquet is also built to support parallel workloads. If your SQL is an Azure Synapse (SQLDW) instance, then ADFDF will use Polybase to manage the upload, which is very fast because it is also built for parallel workloads. I'm not sure how this differs for Azure SQL, and there is no way to tell you what DTU level will work best for your task.

If having Parquet as your end result is acceptable, then that would probably be the easiest and least expensive to configure since it is just blob storage. ADFDF works just fine with Parquet, as either Source or Sink. For ETL workloads, Compute is the most likely IR configuration. The good news is it is the least expensive of the three. The bad news is I have no way to know what the core count should be, you'll just have to find out through trial and error. 50 million rows may sound like a lot, but it really depends on the row size (byte count and column count), and frequency. If the process is running many times a day, then you can include a "Time to live" value in the IR configuration. This will keep the cluster warm while it waits for another job, thus potentially reducing startup time (but incurring more run time cost).